# Why is the child component rendered outside of parent div after updating the state?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a chatroom application like this:

[image: The chatroom layout]

Nothing special and it looks like all the other chatroom app

In the text box div, I wrap all the messages inside, and want to make it scrollable when there are more messages. [image: textbox div that contains the messages]

I store the messages in the state

```
  state = {
    userId: 1,
    currentRoomId: 1,
    conversation: [
      { userId: 1, user: 'a', message: 'hi' },
      { userId: 1, user: 'a', message: "How you doin'?" },
      { userId: 2, user: 'b', message: 'I am fine, thank you.' },
      { userId: 3, user: 'c', message: 'I go to school by bus.' },
    ],
  };
```

And I wrap my messages component in the textbox div

```
 <div className='textBox'>
      <Messages
        conversation={this.state.conversation}
        userId={this.state.userId}
      />
    </div>
```

However, when I type something and press the send button, the state updates and the div reloads, the new messages go out of the div and push the input and send button under the ground

[image: New messages are rendered out of the div]

```
/* Chat containers */
.container {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.textBox {
  height: 60vh;
}
```

Comment: Make the position of the division that has input and send button fixed and bottom 0 property

Comment: can I get the code for the `container`, make the `text-box` container `position:absolute`

Comment: @KALITA Sure, but the problem here is the new child component is rendered outside of the parent component